# Solving a recurence system

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find a function $f(x,y) : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}^2$ such that:

$1 + f(x+1,y) - f(x,y) = a$

$1 + f(x, y+1) - f(x,y) = b$

$k + f(x-k, y) - f(x,y) = c  \space \forall k \leq x$

$k + f(x,y-k) - f(x,y) = d  \space \forall k \leq y$

$k + f(x-k, y+k) - f(x,y) = e  \space \forall k \leq x$

where $a,b,c,d,e$ are some constants.

$f(x,y) = x+y$ works for the first 4 conditions,but I've been trying to find one that will satisfy the fifth as well or prove no such function can exist and I'm stuck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use some general method like generating functions or difference equations.

Comment: @Trismegistos, I'm not sure how I would do that here. Could you elaborate?